# Inquiry of hostname shell script

Tags: shell-script

I can't under stand below script.

GUBUN=${HOSTNAME:${#HOSTNAME}-1:1}

I just know this one call hostname but I can't understand fully.

What I know
${#HOSTNAME}-1 : Call last letter of hostname

If the last hostname's letter is 'x' script is ${HOSTNAME:x:1} : I don't understand this one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In recent shells (`bash`), you could even use

```
echo ${HOSTNAME: -1}
```

as explained in `man bash`:

> **${parameter:offset:length}
>                 Substring  Expansion.**
>
> . . .
>
> If offset evaluates to a number less than zero, the value is used as
>   an offset in characters from the end of the value of parameter.
>
> If length is omitted, ... extending to the end of the value.

(make sure the space is there to avoid interpretation as a "default value")

Comment: Thx I clearly understand :)

Answer (score 1):

${HOSTNAME} is a variable containing your system hostname.

${#HOSTNAME} is the parameter length (characters) of the hostname.

So, using the value of $HOSTNAME, start 1 character from the end (offset) and get the first 1 character(s).

```
kevlinux@ubuntu:~$ echo $HOSTNAME
ubuntu 
kevlinux@ubuntu:~$ echo ${HOSTNAME: ${#HOSTNAME}-1: 1}
u
```

source: man bash and search for Parameter Expansion.